# Unity List Exists only first pass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small routine that check if an entry exists:

```
public class cart {public string name; public int cost; public int amt;}
public string[,] prod_Array = new string[6,2];
public List<cart> cart_array = new List<cart>();
public cart mycart = new cart ();
public void buyProduct (string product) {
    string item = "";
    switch (product) {
    case "fishTank":
        cost = int.Parse(prod_Array[5,1]);
        if(cart_array.Exists(cart => cart.name == "Fish Tank") ){
            cart qty = cart_array.Find(cart => cart.name == "Fish Tank");
            qty.amt= qty.amt+1;
            fillCartTxt(cart_count);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("None found");
            item = "Fish Tank";
            make_cart_text(item, cost);
        }
        break;
    case "growBed":
        cost = int.Parse(prod_Array[4,1]);
        if(cart_array.Exists(cart => cart.name == "Grow Bed")){
            cart qty = cart_array.Find(cart => cart.name == "Grow Bed");
            qty.amt= qty.amt+1;
            fillCartTxt(cart_count);
        } else {
            item = "Grow Bed";
            make_cart_text(item, cost);
        }
        break;
    }
```

It works perfect the first time if you select "Fish Tank" as many times as you want, however, if you select "Grow Bed" after that and then go back and select "Fish Tank" again, it fails and goes to the else statement to create a new text.
Why does it only work the first time?
forgot to add this:

```
void make_cart_text(string item, int cost){
    mycart.name = item;
    mycart.cost = cost;
    mycart.amt = 1;
    int ny = 0;
    cart_array.Add(mycart);
    cart_count = cart_array.Count;
    if (cart_count == 1) {
        ny =50;
    } else if (cart_count > 1) {
        ny = cart_count * 20;
    }
    GameObject cart_line = GameObject.Instantiate(
        Resources.Load("cart_line"),
    new Vector3(19f,ny,0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
    cart_line.name= "carttext"+cart_count;
    GameObject gc2 = GameObject.Find ("Cart");
    cart_line.transform.SetParent(gc2.transform, false);
    fillCartTxt(cart_count);
}
```

Comment: often you find you think your code does one thing but it actually does another. stepping through it with a debugger helps mitigate this issue

Comment: What happens in `make_cart_text`? It would help to get a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) (and the process of creating one can be a great debug process!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding mycart = new cart (); in the first line of make_cart_text before the add statement made it work.
Thanks for all the help.
Jeff